# InsertionSort / Improvements

Tags: sorting, insertion-sort

I have kind of a theoretical question... I am trying to understand different implementations of InsertionSort algorithms and I came across that one specific implementation where the author (before starting the actual sorting) first brought the smallest item to the very first position of the array. Does someone out there know, why this could be an improvement to InsertionSort?

Greetings - Christian

```
for (i = r; i > l; i--) compExch(a, i-1, i);
```